# Not all icons are shown in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements, react-native-vector-icons

I added `react-native-elemets` and `react-native-vector-icons`. I am looking for the icons name in the [official website](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=info&m=free) and by selecting only free icons, and importing icons as following

```
import {Icon } from 'react-native-elements';


    <Icon
        name='comment'
        type='font-awesome'
        size={20}
        color={'grey'}
        style={styles.rightOption}
    />
    <Icon
        name='comment-dots'
        type='font-awesome'
        size={20}
        color={'grey'}
        style={styles.rightOption}
    />
```

Some of the Icons are being shown correctly line the `comment` icon, but some not like the `comment-dot`. Also `circle-info` is for example not working, an `?` char is shown instead of the icon.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using expo to deploy your app?
If you are using some types of icons are not accepted.
I will give you a example of icons if you are using Expo.

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

...

<Icon size={13} name='chevron-circle-right' type='font-awesome' color='#E4AC19' />
```

I will let here the website for icons https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ and this is working only to font awesome icons, you should only use the icons which title on red topbar is FontAwesome